# Install library for jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pip, package, jupyter-notebook

I start my `jupyter` notebook with `python2` as:

`jupyter notebook nameofnotebook`

Then I want to import library like this:

`import scipy`

But I have an error telling that there is no such library.

So I execute in the `notebook` cell:

```
!pip2 install scipy
Requirement already satisfied: scipy in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

How to install package correctly to jupyter kernel?

Comment: There might be multiple versions of python installed. Try `import sys; print(sys.path);` to see where the running jupyter python kernel is looking for installed modules.

Answer (score 5):

[@håken-lid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1977847/h%C3%A5ken-lid) is right. There are probably several versions of python. So to install your package to python where your `jupyter` is located:

```
$ which jupyter
/YOURPATH/bin/jupyter
$ /YOURPATH/bin/pip install scipy
```

This will do for *Python 2.x*

For *Python 3.x* `pip3` will be in `/YOURPATH/bin` instead of single `pip`

Answer (score 2):

You can run pip from python.

```
import pip
pip.main(['install', 'scipy'])
```

If you are using the system python, and running jupyter in a process that doesn't have permission to install global packages, you can use the `--user` flag to install a module for the current user only.

```
pip.main(['install', '--user', 'scipy'])
```

Comment: It provides the error `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'main'`

Comment: It's no longer recommended to use pip as a module.
https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#using-pip-from-your-program